# Directive being really long to load, ways to inspect loading time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

**Tl;dr:** I would like to find a way to inspect the loading time of a recurvise directive, e.g when I load a sub-node I would like to check how much time it took, the content loaded, etc ...

---

Here is the backgroudn of this question, I used an [open-source json-tree viewer](https://github.com/krispo/json-tree) that I modified to fit my graphic style and my needs. I am using it to visualize CouchDB documents, andI had to split it in two separate directives: one only for **viewing** the JSON, and one for **editing** JSON.

Here is the problem: even though the viewer works perfectly fine, the editor is taking an **insane time** displaying the sub-nodes. It can take up to 2 seconds only to show the sub-nodes, and that is a problem.

I was thinking that the boolean conditions on show/hide (I do not want to display `_rev` or `_id` fields, as it would be noxious to modify) were making it slow, and began thinking about some solutions about it. In parallel, It would be useful to get some more informations, like *"How much time does it take to load a sub-node"* or more generally, loading time on directives. The console does not provide that level on details (or maybe I missed something).

Do you know any means in order to achieve this goal ? Any ways to check for loading time of directives or HTML element display ?

**BONUS:** Do you know what can be obnoxious or not about a directive, and ways to improve it's performance while loading ?

Comment: Grab the current time at the beginning of your methods in a var, then at the end console.log the difference between the current time and the time you grabbed at the start of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Also Chrome's Developer tools have a very nice timestrip/graph to show loading times under the Network tab
You'll have a much better overview of what is happening there.
Also cbeck out Chrome's CPU profiles of your scripts to see if anything is bogging the system down.